# How turn off autosave in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio version 0.8.2 (on Windows7). It is very annoying that when i change some file it is automatically saved. According to [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/saving-and-reverting-changes.html#3) i have turn off settings like below (in General, but it doesn't work. Is something else to make this work properly ?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if it is possible to turn autosave off, 
but you can use Local History when you want to change something back 
(Right click -> Local History -> Show History).

Answer (score 5):

## Turnoff Auto Save

> `File` > `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings` > `Synchronization` > then uncheck both `Save files on frame deactivation` and `Save files automatically if application is idle` > `OK`

[image: Screenshot- Disable Auto Save]

---

Now, you should do this too.

## Mark Changed But Unsaved File

> `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `General` > `Editor Tabs` > then check `Mark modified tabs with asterisk` > `OK`

[image: Screenshot- Mark Changed But Unsaved File]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Android Studio(v135.1740770) in Mac Pro, open below file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio/options/ide.general.xml
```

you will see option for autoSaveFiles, just change its value to false.

```
<option name="autoSaveFiles" value="false" />
```

In windows7 same file resides here,

```
~\.AndroidStudioXXX\config\options\ide.general.xml
```

Comment: Hmm...I've got Android Studio 1.3.x, on Windows, and I find the xml file you mention.  But, it is (was) already set to false, yet it is still doing the auto-save.  WTF... (damn, I HATE this feature, that was NOT present in the beta(s) of AS, but now has become the default behavior in V1.x)

Answer (score 2):

The beaviour of "auto-saving" your file is **not** due to the auto-save options mentioned above.

IJ saves all changes to your *build sources* to automatically *build* the target.

This can be turned of in:

`Preferences -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler -> Make project automatically`.

*Note*: now have to initiate the project build manually (e.g. by using an appropriate key-shortcut)

(All other "auto-save" options just fine-tune the build in auto-save behaviour.)